# How to enable cascading parameters in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, cascadingdropdown

I have 5 parameters on my report.
They are `@time_from`, `@time_to`, `@order_id`, `@material`, `@batch`, and `@sscc`

I need to do following:

1. Select time range
2. Fill filters

   1. All orders
   2. All batches
   3. All SSCC
3. Then I must show all data.
   (I did until 4th condition)
4. If all data loaded Operator has option to select 1 order from dropdown, this should **reload** the filters and only show sscc, batch, and material related to that order.

First, after users choose `@time_from` and `@time_to`, the other parameters will be enabled. But rhe fourth case breaks down the first three conditions.
In the fourth condition; `@material`, `@batch` and `@sscc` depends on order_id.
That's why I use cascading parameter. But if I don't select order_id, I cannot select  `@material`, `@batch`, and `@sscc` because they will be disabled.

After selecting `@time_from` and `@time_to` parameter, I want to see all parameters and I want `@material`, `@batch`, and `@sscc` to depend on order_id.

For example; when I select `@time_from` and `@time_to` I must choose `@material` 
but when I select `@time_from` and `@time_to` and then I choose `@order_id`, `@material`, `@batch` and `@sscc` must depend on `@order_id`.

I want to use cascading parameters, but the parameters must not be disabled.

I attached some screenshots. How can I do this?

[1-all parameter depends on time_from and time_to parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptP4F.png)

[2-after I choose @time_from and @time_to I want to show all parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSVv2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you allow null values, you can then set up a SQL query to power your parameters along the lines of..

```
select
    'All' as [Label],
    null as [Value]

union all

select 
    o.Name as [Label],
    o.ID as [Value]
from dbo.Orders as [o]
```

This assumes that your orders have columns for Name and ID.
You can then use this to power the list of available values for the parameter for Orders. 
You can then filter your later queries by using..

```
where (b.ID in (@Orders) or (@Orders) is null)
```

This will check to see if the OrderID is in the list, or if the list of orders is null (thus returning all).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I can choose null value for @order parameter.

Comment: but I click "allow null value" on report parameter properties.

Comment: but I can not show null button near the @order parameter on preview page.

Comment: Your "All" value in the selection is the null value - you don't actually use the tickbox to make it null in this method

Comment: @Aylin I'm not sure what you're asking, I'm afraid. The parameter is a list of values, with "All" at the top which has a null value. You select this value to show all values as though no specific one has been selected. This works if you want single value parameter normally, with an "All" option.